# How to convert mwlib's simpleparse instance into html?

Tags: python, parsing, python-2.7, mediawiki

I have installed the python library `mwlib` which I use to convert any wikimarkup text into a tree. As in:

```
from pprint ipoirt pprint
from mwlib.uparser import simpleparser

foo = """
* Some
* List

== A heading ==
Blah
"""

pprint(simpleparse(foo))
```

Outputs:

```
Article
    Paragraph tagname='p'->'p'
        u'\n'
        ItemList tagname='ul'->'ul'
            Item tagname='li'->'li'
                Node lineprefix=
                    u' Some'
                    u'\n'
            Item tagname='li'->'li'
                Node lineprefix=
                    u' List'
                    u'\n'
    Section tagname='@section' level=2
        Node
            u'A heading '
        Node
            u'\n'
            u'Blah'
            u'\n'
```

But oddly, I cannot find a method that provides me with a way to convert them into HTML?

How do I do so?  By the way, if you have an alternative idea for converting wiki mark-up to html, it would welcome, I am not intending to use `templating` or `referencing` and sorts.

Answer (score 0):

To convert wikitext into HTML you need a parser. If you can't use a MediaWiki install (with the appropriate parser extensions used in your markup), you can try one of the many alternative parsers (none is guaranteed to work).

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers